# Copy and rename on collision

Tags: files, rename, cp

I'd like to merge the content of these folders with a command line.

```
.
├── folder1
│   │ file.txt
│
├── folder2
│   │ file.txt
│
└───folder3
    │ file.txt
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Meaning all 3 files are copied somewhere else with their original directory names as prefixes or???

Comment: you mean you want to merge all `.txt` files into one directory ?

Comment: yes, merge all  .txt file into one directory.

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I can do this with `cp` and its [`--backup`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Backup-options.html#Backup-options) flag.

```
cp --backup=numbered */*.txt new_directory/
```

Comment: you have asked for merging content of all `*.txt` files into one

Comment: I've asked for merging content of folders (aka folder1, folder2, folder3) into on directory

Comment: you should have asked for "files of `folder{1..3}`"

Answer (score 1):

The following command-line loop will copy the (top-level) contents of every folder named "folder*" in your current directory into a directory named "new_directory". The `/*` glob will, by default, not match "dot files"; use `shopt -s dotglob` if you want to change that behavior. If the same (base) filename already exists in new_directory, then it prefixes the destination file with the originating folder (and an underscore), in order to make it unique.

All in one line:

```
for f in folder*/*; do [ ! -e "new_directory/$(basename "$f")" ] && { cp "$f" new_directory/; continue; }; [ -e "new_directory/$(basename "$f")" ] && cp "$f" "new_directory/$(dirname "$f")_$(basename "$f")"; done
```

Broken out for readability:

```
for f in folder*/*
do 
  [ ! -e "new_directory/$(basename "$f")" ] && { cp "$f" new_directory/; continue; }
  [ -e "new_directory/$(basename "$f")" ] && cp "$f" "new_directory/$(dirname "$f")_$(basename "$f")"
done
```

If you intent instead to *move* the files from their original locations, simply change the `cp`'s to `mv`'s.